# Logging in to new Windows 11 PC with school account

Tags: user-accounts, windows-11

I have created a local administration account on a new Windows 11 laptop. Is it possible to use my school account as a laptop signin account? The school accounts have access to MS cloud services such Office 365 and OneDrive. I don't think we have the typical MS "domain infrastructure". A lot of our Windows signin accounts are local. I have added my work/school account to the new Win11 laptop, and the accounts screen indicates it is "connected" to the PC. However my school does not appear as one of the accounts when I power up and am presented with the Windows signon screen. Is it possible to signon to the PC with my Windows school account? If I cannot use the school account at signon, how and when is the school account actually used on Windows 11?

Comment: Unless your school has an AD domain, what you have done, is the farthest linkage you can do. You should be logged into OneDrive, are you?

Comment: Yes, can log into OneDrive and Office 365 using the school account. So the PC will have a local account to login then the "real" school account to access MS cloud apps. If you can post your comment as answer, I will accept.

Comment: Your welcome to answer your question since you already linked your local account to your school account before you submitted your question.